# Lebesgue Measure of $S_k$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

let $S_k$ is the set of elements of $(0,1)$ whose kth position is prime. Then what's is the lebesgue measure of $S_k$

I don't know how to approach the question... Any help leading to answer is deeply appreciable
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the context of the problem? Where did you find this problem?

Comment: The $k$th position of $a$ is prime $\iff$ the $k$th element of the decimal expansion of $a$ is prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_1$ is the set of numbers in $(0,1)$ with prime first digit. The only prime digits are 2, 3, 5, and 7, so this is all numbers that start with $0.2$. $0.3$, $0.5$. or $0.7$. That means

$$
S_1 = [0.2,0.3) \cup [0.3,0.4) \cup [0.5,0.6) \cup [0.7,0.8) ,
$$

and $\mu(S_1) = \frac{4}{10}$.

What is $S_2$?

There is technically an ambiguity: $0.3999\dots = 0.4$, so is it in $S_1$ or not? However, this doesn't affect the answer, why?

Comment: $\mu(S_k) = \frac{4}{10}$ why ? It is the measure of $s_1$ right? and $\mu(S_k) = ({\frac{4}{10}})^k$ because we can further divide  those intervals as k increases

Comment: That was a bad typo on my part. I meant $\mu(S_1)$.

Comment: First convince yourself what $S_2$ and $S_3$ look like.